# Insert Data from Form to MySQL database, javascript and flask

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, ajax, flask

I am creating a web app for nearby events, and one of the important features is the option to create events. As of now I have a modal that contains a form. I'm having trouble taking the inputs of the form on submit and adding it to the database, using javascript and a python flask web app.

Here is my html:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="eventInput" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create an Event</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
    <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Event Name" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Start date and time:
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="start" placeholder="Start date and time" type="datetime-local"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                End date and time:
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="end" placeholder="End date and time" type="datetime-local"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="place" placeholder="Location Name" type="text"/>
            </div>

            Please use <a href="https://www.google.com/maps">Google Maps</a> to determine the accurate latitude and longitude of your event location
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="lat" placeholder="Location Latitude" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="long" placeholder="Location Longitude" type="text"/>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Event</button>
      </div>

    </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
   $(function() {
    $('submit').click(function() {
        var event = {
        'title': document.getElementById('title').value,
        'description': document.getElementById('description').value,
        'start': document.getElementById('start').value,
        'end': document.getElementById('end').value,
        'place': document.getElementById('place').value
       };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/createEvent',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And python:

```
# Add Event to database
@app.route('/createEvent', methods=['POST'])
def createvent() :
    title =  request.form['title'];
    description = request.form['description'];
    place = request.form['place'];
    start = request.form['start'];
    end = request.form['end'];
    db.execute("INSERT INTO events (user_id, title, description, place, start, end) VALUES (:user, :title, :description, :place, :start, :end)",
                user=session["user_id"], title=title, description=description, place=place, start=start, end=end)
    return render_template("list.html")
```

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: newEvent is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `onsubmit="return newEvent()"` from the form in the html code?

Comment: That makes the error go away, but event still does not save to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Id to your form and, and remove the onsubmit event and use it only in jquery.
all  your forms element doesn't have id attribute add them like this :

the html :

```
<div id="eventInput" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create an Event</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
    <form  id="target" action="/destination">
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="title"   id= "title" placeholder="Event Name" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="description"  id ="description" placeholder="Description" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Start date and time:
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="start" id="start" placeholder="Start date and time" type="datetime-local"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                End date and time:
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="end" id ="end" placeholder="End date and time" type="datetime-local"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="place" id ="place" placeholder="Location Name" type="text"/>
            </div>

            Please use <a href="https://www.google.com/maps">Google Maps</a> to determine the accurate latitude and longitude of your event location
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="lat" id="lat" placeholder="Location Latitude" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="long" id="long" placeholder="Location Longitude" type="text"/>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Event</button>
      </div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

and your javascript like this :

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var new_event = {
        'title': document.getElementById('title').value,
        'description': document.getElementById('description').value,
        'start': document.getElementById('start').value,
        'end': document.getElementById('end').value,
        'place': document.getElementById('place').value
       };
       console.log(new_event);


$.ajax({
        url: '/createEvent',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Though the action tag does let me go to the page I'd like to end on, unfortunately the event is still not saving.